# php, mysql insert but no appear on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I try to insert some details on my database in phpmyAdmin/mySql using a php, but it doesn't appear/update on the phpmyAdmin/mySql. Also confusing there's no error appears. Below is my code on php:
php code

[image]

There's no problem on connection on mySql because I check it and I can read data from mySQL to php. but the problem I can insert data on mySQL using php. Please help me. Thank you

[image]

Comment: What is that null in your insert query? Why it is added?

Comment: apology. please disregard the null. its just a try.

Comment: Can you edit your question to post the codes ?? Images are not the way you post code here .

Comment: error in you query near last extra `comma` `,` . so remove you last `comma ,` working fine

Comment: @VadivelS thank you so much. i didn't double check. hehe Thank you

Comment: On a security-note, you are **vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks**, take a read at [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). And for further questions, please don't post screenshots of code - post your actual code here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The insert Query written has an extra comma just before you close the brackets. Please remove that. It should work fine.